# upload image from url to wordpress using rest api and python

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress

I'm trying to upload image from url to **wordpress** without saving it in my device using **python and rest api** , i'm really close to achive that i just can't find where i'm lost
i keep getting 500 and this error :

```
{"code":"rest_upload_unknown_error","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.","data":{"status":500}}
```

my code :

```
import base64, requests


def header(user, password):
    credentials = user + ':' + password
    token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
    header_json = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
                   'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=%s'% "test1.jpg"}
    return header_json

def upload_image_to_wordpress(file_path, header_json):
    media = {'file': file_path,'caption': 'My great demo picture'}
    responce = requests.post("https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media", headers = header_json, files = media)
    print(responce.text)

heder = header("user","password") #username, application password   


url  = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/11/30/08/24/strawberries-6834750_1280.jpg"
raw =  requests.get(url).content
upload_image_to_wordpress(raw,heder)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying many solutions i found out working one

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

url  = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/11/30/08/24/strawberries-6834750_1280.jpg"
raw = requests.get(url).content
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,mode="wb",suffix=".jpg") as img :
    img.write(raw)

    # print(f.file())

    c  =  open(img.name,"rb")

    upload_image_to_wordpress(c,heder)
```